How does an electromagnetic wave warp spacetime?
I am trying to understand how an electromagnetic wave would curve spacetime and what effect this curvature in turn would have on the wave.
I am imagining an electromagnetic plane wave travelling in the $z$-direction, while the electric and magnetic field are oriented in $x$- and $y$-directions respectively. Since the electric and magnetic field both contain energy, it is sensible to assume that they will warp spacetime in some way. Specifically, since an electromagnetic wave consists of periodically changing electric and magnetic fields, I believe that it would cause a form of gravitational wave also moving in the $z$-direction, that is a periodic "stretching and squeezing" of spacetime in the $x$- and $y$-dimension. Suppose the $x$-dimension is expanded ("stretched") and the $y$-dimension contracted ("squeezed") at one instant. Then the energy density of the electric field would be reduced, while that of the magnetic field would be increased. This, in turn, would have an effect on the curvature of spacetime and so on. Is this reasoning correct? If so, electric and magnetic fields  wouldn't be of equal magnitude at each instant (as is usually assumed), but slightly stretched or squeezed.
To approach this problem quantitatively, I believe you have to solve the Einstein-Maxwell equations. I have stumbled upon a possible solution, namely the Monochromatic Electromagnetic Plane Wave, but I do not understand it, or even whether it is relevant to my question or not. If it really does describe the spacetime curvature caused by any electromagnetic wave, why is it so niche, i.e. why isn't it listed in common examples of solutions to the EFE, or why isn't it widely taught in GR classes?
Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Concerning the last questions, which IMO are more opinion-based:  most physically realistic EM waves would involve minimal curvature of spacetime, and can be well approximated without reference to spacetime curvature. So it makes sense pedagogically to focus on solutions to the Einstein equations (Schwarzschild, gravitational waves, etc.) that more obviously require the machinery of GR to describe measurable effects.

The net energy density (electric + magnetic energy density) of a mode of the EM field is constant in time even though the electric and magnetic field amplitudes are locally oscillating. So I think that rules out your idea the EM waves generate gravitational waves.
Naively I would guess you could have a GR model where the EM stress energy tensor contributes one-for-one to the stress-energy tensor appearing in Maxwell's field equations, but my GR knowledge is weak.

The Monochromatic EM Plane Wave solution of EFE that you found, is correct and relevant. It is quite complicated, as you have noted, and not very physically interesting to see, and that explains why it is not usually treated.

Yes, there are plane wave solutions of the Einstein-Maxwell equations. Indeed there are various parallel plane wave solutions to the Einstein equations, the pp-wave spacetimes. They correspond to spacetimes where radiation moves in one direction at the speed of light. Since the radiation provides nonzero terms in the stress-energy tensor there is also gravitational radiation at the same time.
The general form of pp-waves is $$ds^2=H(u,x,y)du^2+2dudv+dx^2+dy^2$$ where $H$ is any smooth function and $(u,v,x,y)$ are Brinkmann coordinates where $u,v$ correspond to coordinates where $v$ is taken to be a null wave vector for the radiation field and $u$ is suitably orthogonal. If you have waves along $z$ you might use $u=t+z, v=t-z$ for example. The monochromatic electromagnetic plane wave is a special case of this.
Generally, these solutions are used in the literature. Axisymmetric ones like the Bonnor beam and the Aichelburg-Sexl ultraboost are pretty well known. The Penrose limit shows that near null geodesics everything looks like a pp-wave spacetime. But I suspect they are rarely used in the introductory textbooks because they do have some nontrivial causality and math.

Hang on, I thought the pp-wave solution is a vacuum solution describing gravitational waves, not EM ones.

It can be. But it can also have a nonzero stress-energy tensor. The function H can be almost anything, so it is a vast class of solutions.

This is a good question. The answer is tricky, because it requires that you look at the electromagnetic wave as part of a system. Considered in isolation, a light pulse can be made to have arbitrarily small energy and momentum by boosting to an appropriate frame. So it doesn't really have any intrinsic effect on spacetime. However, it does carry energy, and so relative to another light pulse (or massive body) it can contribute to the stress energy tensor.
Tolman et al looked at gravitational effects of light pulses and found that two light pulses traveling in the same direction have no effect on one another, whereas if they are traveling in opposite directions they will attract each other.

Why is it tricky? Why doesn't the EM stress energy tensor just directly contribute to the stress energy tensor in the field equations?

It depends on whether you're interested in interior solutions (inside the EM wave, where you would indeed use the EM stress energy tensor) or exterior solutions, to find how the EM wave affects matter/energy outside of it. I interpreted the OP to be asking about the latter.
